# What is the inverse function for addTo in domain classes

Tags: grails, grails-orm

In grails we can use the addToPages function to add pages to a book. For example, if web have the class Book that have many pages, we can write:

```
book.addToPages(page)
```

But how can we remove a page from a book?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`removeFrom` - see http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Domain%20Classes/removeFrom.html